# Jquery- Modify Element Value after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, element

scenario: I want to do an ajax call to update the image shown. Example: click to activate, click again to deactivate.

Now, the image can change correctly when clicking for the first time.

After that, if I click the img again, changes won't reflect anymore.

The reason, the onclick status still= yes
How do I access the hyperlink element to rewrite the onclick part to onclick="update('7', 'no') at REFER HERE?

```
<a href="#" onclick="update('7','yes')" ><img id=img7 border=0 src="img/active.gif" ></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(pk, enable) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxcall.asp",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (output) {
                var status = output
                if (status == 1) {
                    var src = ($('#' + 'img' + pk).attr("src") == "img/cross.gif") ? "img/tick.gif" : "img/cross.gif";
                    $('#' + 'img' + pk).attr("src", src);
                    //REFER HERE
                }
            },
            complete: function () { },
            data: 'pk=' + pk + '&enable=' + enable
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way. Firstly:

```
<a id="a7" href="#"><img border="0" src="img/active.gif"></a>
```

then

```
$(function() {
  $("#a7").update("7");
});

function update(pk) {
  var img = $("#img" + pk);
  if (img.attr("src") == "img/cross.gif") {
    enable = "no";
    var src = "img/cross.gif";
  } else {
    enable = "yes";
    var src = "img/tick.gif";
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajaxcall.asp",
    type: "POST",                       
    success:  function(output) {
      var status = output;
      if (status == 1) {
        img.attr("src", src);
      }
    },
    complete: function(){ },
    data: 'pk='+pk+'&enable='+enable
  });         
}
```

You don't need to pass in yes or no. You can derive it from the image src.

Comment: I haven't think of this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**The easy way out:**

Replace this:

```
$('#'+'img'+pk).attr("src", src);
```

with this:

```
$('#'+'img'+pk).attr("src", src).parent('a').attr('onClick','update("7","no")').
```

**The right way:**

This Javascript should be [unobtrusive](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/). If it were, you could use jQuery's event binding system to run the event once, then unbind it.

Comment: Hi there, I found that this method only work in Firefox, not IE. Any workaround?

Comment: easy way. It works well in FF, but IE having no respond after the first click. $('#'+'img'+pk).attr("src", src).parent('a').attr('onClick','update("7","no")')